# ToS and Privacy policy links in sign-in with Google not working

Tags: android, firebase-authentication

I have implemented the firebase authentication UI including the email and Google as providers.
I have also included the ToS and privacy policy links as follows:

```
List<AuthUI.IdpConfig> providers = Arrays.asList(
                    new AuthUI.IdpConfig.EmailBuilder().build(),
                    new AuthUI.IdpConfig.GoogleBuilder().build());


            // Create and launch sign-in intent
            startActivityForResult(
                    AuthUI.getInstance()
                            .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                            .setTosAndPrivacyPolicyUrls(
                                    "https://test.com/terms-and-conditions/",
                                    "https://test.com/privacy-policy/")
                            .setLogo(getApp().isDemoApplication() ? R.drawable.log1 : R.drawable.log2)
                            .setTheme(R.style.LoginTheme)
                            .setAvailableProviders(providers)
                            .build(),
                    RC_SIGN_IN);
```

The links work perfectly fine in the first page but when I choose the Google option for authentication, then the links in the popup do not work and keep showing the toast saying "No browser found to open this link."

I have followed the instructions to reset my apps configurations, also reset my phone(s) and changed my default browser to chrome. But none of them solved the issue. I have tested this on two android phones; Sony Xperia with android 10 and Samsung Galaxy s8 with android 9.

Is there any settings I missed in my AuthUI or in my app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the exact same problem, you have to add the Application Privacy Policy AND the Application Terms of Service links into the Google Cloud console.

They can be added by visiting the following URL: [Project ID is [PROJECT-ID], and authorise the domain used in those links.]

[https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials/consent/edit?project=[PROJECT-ID]](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials/consent/edit?project=%5BPROJECT-ID%5D)

Comment: I will give a try soon but as i understood from my quick read, it needs to be reviewed and if there is any special scope then it may take longer and even cost money. My app is already in production, so how this is gonna affect it?

Comment: OK, I just added the links and pressed "save and continue", but did not finish all the steps. And now they are working. Maybe you can add this to your answer.

Answer (score 2):

as I see your are using an old version.

You can follow this guide to use the last version without "startActivityForResult".
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/firebaseui

I had the same problem when I used the URL´s without "https://". Is the code you posted an example or is the real one?

Comment: I tested the new version but the links are still not working when I am choosing the accounts from Google Smart Lock. The real URLs have the https and they work in the AuthUI activity!

Comment: hi @msc87 did you ever get this working?

Comment: @Kibi: unfortunately no.

Comment: Thanks @msc87 I will try another question

Comment: @Kibi: There is a new and correct answer here. Please check it out and see if that works for you too!