# Firebase Auth using setTosAndPrivacyPolicyUrls does not provide clickable links

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication

I am following the instructions from [firebase themselves](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/firebaseui) using the newest implementations I can find

```
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:12.0.1'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:12.0.1'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:7.2.0'
```

I have a custom layout, including this:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/terms_and_conditions"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:autoLink="all"
    android:fontFamily="@font/omnes_light"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:linksClickable="true"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="20dp"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
    android:textSize="16dp"
    android:text="@string/terms_and_conditions_login"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />
```

and I have also tried alternating in and out these lines

```
    android:linksClickable="true"
    android:text="@string/terms_and_conditions_login"
```

and taking out the tools:text line

Where the string is

```
<string name="terms_and_conditions_login">By continuing, you are indicating that you accept\nour <a href="https://www.mycompany.com/terms-conditions/">Terms of Service</a> and <a href="https://www.mycompany.com/privacy-policy/">Privacy Policy</a>.</string>
```

Then in my code I have

```
private fun login() {
    val selectedProviders = mutableListOf<AuthUI.IdpConfig>()
    selectedProviders.add(AuthUI.IdpConfig.GoogleBuilder().build())
    selectedProviders.add(AuthUI.IdpConfig.FacebookBuilder().build())
    selectedProviders.add(AuthUI.IdpConfig.EmailBuilder().build())


    val customLayout = AuthMethodPickerLayout
            .Builder(R.layout.activity_login_init)
            .setGoogleButtonId(R.id.google_button)
            .setFacebookButtonId(R.id.facebook_button)
            .setEmailButtonId(R.id.email_button)
            .setTosAndPrivacyPolicyId(R.id.terms_and_conditions)
            .build()


    val authUi = AuthUI.getInstance().createSignInIntentBuilder()
            .setAuthMethodPickerLayout(customLayout)
            .setAvailableProviders(selectedProviders)
            .setTheme(R.style.AppTheme_NoActionBar)
            .setIsSmartLockEnabled(false)
            .enableAnonymousUsersAutoUpgrade()
            .setTosAndPrivacyPolicyUrls("https://www.mycompany.com/terms-conditions/", "https://www.mycompany.com/privacy-policy/")
            .build()

    signInLauncher.launch(authUi)

}
```

So: the buttons work correctly, but the Text at the bottom for the terms of service shows the text with just the words "Privacy Policy" in blue and none of it clickable. Also, as noted in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68818635/tos-and-privacy-policy-links-in-sign-in-with-google-not-working/68840560?noredirect=1#comment123246136_68840560) when I get to the Google login, both links give an error that "No browser found to open this link"

In the facebook login, one link works and one doesn't (Terms and conditions doesn't work). In the Email login, both work perfectly. Obviously, I have checked the links and they are fine in all normal cases.

Does anyone have an idea how to get this working correctly?

**Edit 17/7/22** I posted this question on the [Firebase Github](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/2007) and just a couple of days ago got a response! The suggestion was to remove the `android:autoLink` attribute from my custom layout textview. It **partially** solved my problem. So now on the main Login page, I see two correct clickable links and they click through to the correct pages.

Still, when I click on the Google login, both blue links give an error: "No browser found to open this link". In the Facebook login the "terms and conditions" link goes to some bad address with a 404 (our link is ourwebsite.../terms-conditions/ but for some reason it is trying to go to ourwebsite..../terms-of-service/ ) and on the email logon they work.

Anyway, it's a bit of progress

Comment: Note that I have updated the question has been partially solved by support at Firebase github

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the people on the [firebase  github](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/2007) really do answer questions

There were a couple of parts to the answer

1. Remove the `android:autoLink="all"` from the custom layout
2. From this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73019599/240795) I fixed the links in the Google login
3. For Facebook login, go to [developers console](https://developers.facebook.com/apps/), choose your app, and under Settings > Basic correctly set the URLs

Thanks to [Rosário Pereira Fernandes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5861618/ros%C3%A1rio-pereira-fernandes) for the help

Answer (score 0):

Hello if someone need answer about Privacy Policy you need to add privacy policy link and terms and condition link in google developer console under APIs & Services -> OAuth consent screen -> App domain

Create new OAuth consent if not created already else just click on edit app option under OAuth consent screen.

Comment: Hi @Yaroslav: if I set up a new OAuth consent what "Scope" am i supposed to use? The current OAuth is coming via Firebase, but that is not one of the 31 options given on the page when I select "Add or Remove Scopes"